# Linear regression with SGD using pyspark.ml.linearegression

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, linear-regression, apache-spark-ml, sgd

I'm using the LinearRegression model in the Spark ML for prediction.

```
import pyspark.ml.regression.LinearRegression

featureassembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[‘Year’, ‘Present_Price’, 
                                              ‘Kms_Driven’, ‘Owner’], 
                                   outputCol=’features’)

output = featureassembler.transform(df)
data = output.select('features', 'Selling_Price')

# Initializing a Linear Regression model
ss = LinearRegression(featuresCol='features', labelCol='Selling_Price')
```

I want to test the linear regression with SGD(Stochastic Gradient Descent.) but pyspark.ml does not propose any linearregressionwithSGD like mllib. Also, when accessing the mllib linear regressionwithSGD i found that it Deprecated since version 2.0.0.

How can i use ml for linear regression with SGD. Is there any parameter that i can use for that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `ml` you can use `mllib`:

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint, LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel
```

Here is the documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/mllib-linear-methods.html